# Confused about nested resources in RoR forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

My intent is to be able to edit a wine product and its associated awards/reviews in one form.  So going to the page "http://mydomain.com/wines/cab-sauv/edit" shows the form in which I can edit the name, year, etc.  It will also generate the list of awards and reviews so that I can add/remove/edit each award and review.  Saving the wine will automatically save/update/delete the awards and reviews.

I'm having trouble generating the form for the nested objects (awards and reviews).  The following is a modified example of what I'm currently attempting to do:

```
<% form_for @wine do |w| %>
    Stock: <%= w.text_field :stock, :size => 12 %>
    <% @wine.awards.each do |awd| %>
        Award: <%= w.select ???, @medals %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not really getting nested resources when it comes to forms.  Is there something I have to do in the routes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<% form_for @wine do |w| %>
   Stock: <%= w.text_field :stock, :size => 12 %>
   <% w.fields_for :awards do |awd| %>
     Award: <%= awd.select :awd_field_name, @medals %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

In the file app/models/wine.rb, make sure you call this line somewhere,

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :awards
```

You can read this excellent tutorial for nested resources too. http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes. Good luck!

Comment: Excellent!  On another question that's related to this, what would be the least DB-intensive way to store a list of all medal types?  I currently just do a "@medals = Medal.all" query in the controller...

Comment: Can you state the relationship between Medal, Award, and Wine?

Comment: Wine has many awards...Award has one medal, belongs to wine...Medal has many awards

Comment: I think for the association, award should belongs to medal and medal should have many awards. I'm guess medal is like a static table for you right? Depending on your purposes. You can also call eager loading to load award and medals whenever you load wine by calling<br /><b>@wine = Wine.all(:include => [ { :awards => :medal } ])</b>. awards and medal should be the name of your association. That will load all wine, awards, and medal for you in 3 queries. If you want to learn more about this, google "Rails eager loading". I hope that answers your question!

Comment: In addition, I think award should belongs_to medal because I'm guessing you are storing the award_id inside of your award table right? Whenever you have two models associated with each other, the table/model that stores the foreign_key to the other table/model should call belongs_to :the_other_model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look at the Railscast for nested model forms:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2